# Creating an efficient friendlist using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-design, tree-structure

I would like to build a website that has some elements of a social network.

So I have been trying to think of an efficient way to store a friend list (somewhat like Facebook).

And after searching a bit the only suggestion I have come across is making a "table" with two "ids" indicating a friendship.

That might work in small websites but it doesn't seem efficient one bit.

I have a background in Java but I am not proficient enough with PHP.

An idea has crossed my mind which I think could work pretty well, problem is I am not sure how to implement it.

the idea is to have all the "id"s of your friends saved in a tree data structure,each node in that tree resembles one digit from the friend's id.

first starting with 1 node, and then adding more nodes as the user adds friends.
(A bit like Lempel–Ziv).

every node will be able to point to 11 other nodes, 0 to 9 and X.

"X" marks the end of the Id.

for example see this tree:

[An Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtYSJ.gif)

In this tree the user has 4 friends with the following "id"s:

- 0
- 143
- 1436
- 15

**Update:** as it might have been unclear before, the idea is that every user will have a tree in a form of multidimensional array in which the existence of the pointers themselves indicate the friend's "id".

If every user had such a multidimensional array, searching if id "y" is a friend of mine, deleting id "y" from my friend list or adding id "y" to my friend list would all require constant time O(1) without being dependent on the number of users the website might have, only draw back is, taking such a huge array, serializing it and pushing it into each row of the table just doesn't seem right.

-Is this even possible to implement?

-Would using serializing to insert that tree into a table be practical?

-Is there any better way of doing this?

The benefits upon which I chose this is that even with a really large number of ids (millions or billions) the search,add,delete time is linear (depends of the number of digits).

I'd greatly appreciate any help with implementing this or any suggestions for alternative ways to improve or change this method.

Comment: "it doesn't seem efficient one bit." Why's that?

Comment: A `Friendships` table with just two `id`s is a solid plan. Don't implement something that will cause your successor to hunt you down to punch you in the face. :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but see my response to Matt's answer as to why it's inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advise against this.

- **Storage savings are not significant, and may (probably?) be worse**.  In a real dataset, the actual space-savings afforded to you with this approach are minimal.  Computing the average savings is a very difficult problem, but use some real numbers and try a few samples with random IDs.  If you have a million users, consider a user with 15 friends.  How much data do you save with this approch?  You may actually use more space, since tree adjacency models can require significant data.
- **"Rendering" a list of users requires CPU investment.**
- **Inserts are non-deterministic and non-trivial.**  When you add a new user to an existing tree, you will have a variety of methods of inserting them.  Assuming you don't choose arbitrarily, it is difficult to compute which approach is the best (and would only be based on heuristics).

This are the big ones that came to my mind.  But generally, I think you are over-thinking this.

Comment: Actually this method as I see it is high on storage and low on CPU.

As the time for each action is linear.
Assuming the website has a million users the height of the tree is anywhere from 1 to 10, going down 10 levels in a tree is what I would consider linear.

Comment: But add/remove actions in the simple "link table" are not linear or O(n), they are O(1), which cannot be improved upon.  Additionally, with the use of database indexes, lookups for friends' lists are efficient.

Comment: Hmmm, What about the case where I would like to know if user id "x" is my friend or not, will the lookout through such a huge amount of friendship be that fast? (assuming the number is really large).

Or if I wanted to print a list of all my friends, would going through a table which holding millions of friendships be that fast? I'd have to go through millions of relationships that are irrelevant to me.

Comment: You are absolutely right - if the database isn't indexed.  But indexing has a gigantic impact on performance.  See here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work .  Good luck on your project!

Comment: Thank you for that link, I learned a lot about indexing in there, but I am still not certain a table with indexing is the way to go, I will be researching this topic some more before making a decision (hopefully with the insight of more answers).

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [OQGRAPH](http://openquery.com/products/graph-engine), the Open Query graph storage engine.  It is designed to handle efficient tree and graph storage for MySQL.

You can also check out my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data), or my answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462) here on Stack Overflow.

I describe a design I call **Closure Table**, which records all paths between ancestors and descendants in a hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

You say 'using PHP' in the title, but this seems to be just a database question at its heart. And believe it or not the linking table is by far the best way to go. Especially if you have millions or billions of users. It would be faster to process, easier to handle in the PHP code and smaller to store.

**Update**

Users table:

```
  id    |   name   |   moreInfo
   1    |    Joe   |     stuff
   2    |    Bob   |     stuff
   3    |   Katie  |     stuff
   4    |   Harold |     stuff
```

Friendship table:

```
   left   |   right
    1     |     4
    1     |     2
    3     |     1
    3     |     4
```

In this example Joe knows everyone and Katie knows Harold.

This is of course a simplified example.

I'd love to hear if someone has a better logic to the left and right and an explanation as to why.

**Update**

I gave some php code in a comment below but it was marked up wrong so here it is again.

```
$sqlcmd = sprintf( 'SELECT IF( `left` = %1$d, `right`, `left`) AS "friend" FROM `friendship` WHERE `left` = %1$d OR `right` = %1$d', $userid);
```

Comment: The linking table does not seem efficient one bit, why should I go through a list holding all the relationship on the website (could be exponential to the number of users) when in reality I could have only one friend, obviously any method that requires you to go through huge amount of unnecessary data is not optimal.

Especially if the "unnecessary data" is the other billion relationships.

Comment: I believe you are looking at the linking table the wrong way. If one user had one friend then only row would exist. And you would build the script to search both id columns to eliminate reversed duplicates. I've added to my answer illustrate the database tables.

Comment: I looked at the table as if it wasn't ordered, but having it ordered is of course a lot better, that said, ordering the table after every insert will take time I am assuming O(log(n)) at best even if the database does it on it's own without me having to code this.

Comment: I truly think you're missing how much indexing will play a part in this. Ordering the table will not be necessary. Providing the example I gave and this php: $sqlcmd = sprintf( 'SELECT IF( `left` = %1$d, `right`, `left`) AS "friend" FROM `friendship` WHERE `left` = %1$d OR `right` = %1$d', $userid); I'm querying 3 million rows in thousands of a second.

Answer (score 1):

Few ideas:

- ordered lists - searching through ordered list is fast, though ordering itself might be heavier;
- horizontal partitioning data;
- getting rid of premature optimizations.